# Okhttp how to prevent Fiddler capture https request?

Tags: https, fiddler, okhttp, capture

Okhttp how to prevent Fiddler capture https request:

[image: Okhttp how to prevent Fiddler capture https request]

Comment: Can you say what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Work with your server’s TLS administrator to adopt [certificate pinning](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html). Be careful: certificate pinning done wrong may prevent your app from being able to connect to your server when the server updates its certificates.